# How do I work with objects in lists and can I create multiple objects with different names in a loop?

Tags: java, list, loops, object

I need to create Objects of a class called "Tile". I have 9x9 chess board like grid and want to initiate the whole board at once. The position of a Tile is defined by an x and y-axis and I need to work with those later.

I thought about doing it with a loop but I want each object to have different names if that is possible.

The following code works for creating a List and filling it with the Objects I need.
My question is, how can I work with Elements in that list?
`tileList.get("index")."attribute"`doesn't work.

Every advice on how you would do it in a different way is appreciated, as I am really trying to learn.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Tile> tileList = new ArrayList<Tile>(9);

    //These loops just set the values for the Coordinates
    //a total of 9 Objects is created    
        for(int i = 1; i<4; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j<4; j++) {
                
            Tile t = new Tile(i,j);
            tileList.add(t);
        }
```

Comment: public class Tile {

   private String name;

   private int x; 

   private int y;
   // Add getters and setters
}
Read about encapsulation https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_encapsulation.asp

Comment: What do you mean by tileList.get("index")."attribute" doesn't work?

Comment: @Md.KawserHabib If I want to call a specific object in that list I tried to use this syntax ```tileList.get(0).xCo``` (for the x-coordinate of that Tile) because Eclipse suggested just adding ```.xCo``` but I bet it's not actually that easy.

Comment: @BE01 Oh, so instead of having every object initiated with a different name, i could just call them in the list and set their names to what I want to have them? That's cool!

Comment: Maybe it's worth to use a 2D array of Tiles `Tile[][] board = new Tile[9][9];` instead of linear array list?  Then it would be possible to get a tile on the board using indexes in the array.

Comment: @AlexRudenko I'm a beginner and this is a private project of mine, somewhen I'll have to do my first GUI with this and I think having coordinates assigned to every tile should be enough to determine location. Do you think this is not a good solution?

Comment: I don't quite understand the advantage of storing coordinates _inside_ tile, and then putting the tiles into linear arraylist and accessing the tile by the index in this arraylist.

Comment: @AlexRudenko I solely did this because I did not find another way of creating a set number of Objects in one go. I use a loop, but since I can't rename every individual object I need a way to distinguish them from another, hence the List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists are not like normal array , its mutable , you don't need to specify your list length , so you can declare a list simply like :

```
List<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<>(); 
//then you fill it using nested for 
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
tiles.add(new Tile(i,j));
}
}
```

your list now should have 9 point of (x,y) pair , thier value is :
(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)

you can access a specific item by using :

```
Tile myTile = tiles.get(yourIndex);
```

if your Tile class has a property x , you can get it like :

```
int x = myTile.getX();
```

Note : I assumed that you have getters in your Tile class .

You can check this  [simple tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-list) to better understand of how lists works .

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your solution, but Eclipse tells me that the constructor of Tile is undefined. The Tile class is in another package, maybe that is the problem? i already imported it to my main class.

Comment: Sorry, I actually had no constructor. Fixed it! thank you!

Comment: @localvariableisnotused, the code is almost the same as in the original question -- where `Tile` constructor _was supposedly_ used too.  The main difference is that the indexes/tile coordinates are in range `[0..2]` here, while in the question they are in `[1..3]`.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Yes, it accomplishes the same, but it also did give me another perspective on how to work with objects and lists. I never used getter and setter before.